# Create json with multiple entries in python

Tags: python, json

How can I generate the json below in python? I have tried with a dictionary but the first book was constantly overwritten.

```
{
    "book":[
        {
            "category":"reference",
            "author":"Nigel Rees"
        },
        {
            "category":"fiction",
            "author":"Evelyn Waugh"
        },
        {
            "category":"fiction",
            "author":"J. R. R. Tolkien"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: From which source do you want to generate this JSON?

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?  Show your work

Comment: it is a modified example from https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import json 

text = """{
    "book":[
        {
            "category":"reference",
            "author":"Nigel Rees"
        },
        {
            "category":"fiction",
            "author":"Evelyn Waugh"
        },
        {
            "category":"fiction",
            "author":"J. R. R. Tolkien"
        }
    ]
}"""    

# parse your text:
results = json.loads(text)
  
# print your results as dictionary:
print(results)
```

It will get your the output as follows:

```
{'book': [{'category': 'reference', 'author': 'Nigel Rees'}, {'category': 'fiction', 'author': 'Evelyn Waugh'}, {'category': 'fiction', 'author': 'J. R. R. Tolkien'}]}
```

Comment: I would like to build the json from scratch

Comment: Ah got it :) Sorry, I misread the question. 

Perhaps, you could create a class and create a list of objects and load it as json.

Answer (score 0):

In python a dictionary is already valid json.

```
$cat /tmp/3824
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json

x = {
    "book":[
        {
            "category":"reference",
            "author":"Nigel Rees"
        },
        {
            "category":"fiction",
            "author":"Evelyn Waugh"
        },
        {
            "category":"fiction",
            "author":"J. R. R. Tolkien"
        }
    ]
}
print(json.dumps(x, indent=3))
```

So if you execute it.

```
$/tmp/3824
{
   "book": [
      {
         "category": "reference",
         "author": "Nigel Rees"
      },
      {
         "category": "fiction",
         "author": "Evelyn Waugh"
      },
      {
         "category": "fiction",
         "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien"
      }
   ]
}
```